# Riemann Lower Sum by definition

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I have asked a similar question before, and didn't get the answer I was looking for, so i'll try to be more clear here.
If necessary here is the link:
[Riemann sums upper and lower sums question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375175/riemann-sums-upper-and-lower-sums-question)

Okay I am trying to find the lower Riemann sum.

The question is $f(x)=(x-2)^{2} +1, [a,b]=1,3,$  find the lower sum with $n=3.$

An answer given by someone:
'''
f′(x)=$2(x−2)$

For $n=3$, the partition of $[1,3]$ is

the 3 sub intervals $[1,5/3]$ and $[5/3,7/3]$ and $[7/3,3]$

f is decreasing at $[1,2]$ and increasing at $[2,3]$.

in $[5/3,7/3]$ the minimum of f(x) is f($2$)= $1$

the lower sum is
$2/3$*(($(5/3 −2)^2 +1)$+$1$+($(7/3 −2)^2) +1)$

'''

I have two major questions:

1. I see the derivative was taken, was this to see where f was increasing and decreasing? If so how do I do this, just plug in the partitioned values in the derivative?
2. By definition of a lower sum our delta x was 2/3, which implies our 
   x_k=a+k*(delta x) = 1+(2/3)k. We did not use this x_k anywhere, why is it necessary to calculate this(my text does it), I know in a right sum we would plug this x_k anywhere their is an x, but we didn't do that here.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yesterday i gave you the right answer but it seems you are looking for noon at twelve.

Comment: One: I have not seen the previous question but judging by the amount of clumsy copy-pasting I'd say this is a repetition of the previous question. That is against the rules. Two: Even if it is a different question you need to link us to it. Three: Nobody can give you a good answer if they can't read your question. I mean the least you could do was to read what you wrote once. Four: "Here is the answer given by some nice person"??? I really hope that is not sarcasm...

Comment: Previous question: [Riemann sums upper and lower sums question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375175/riemann-sums-upper-and-lower-sums-question).  Note you didn't even take the time to copy/paste the MathJax from there. How are we supposed to look at `f(x)=(x-2)2+1` and think this is supposed to mean $f(x)=(x-2)^2+1$. Sorry, but I'm downvoting and voting to close this question for two main reasons: The equations are too hard to read. For some basic information about writing math at this site see [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  Secondly, as @Hamed mentions, you should clear up your question *a lot*.  This not only applies to the math, but you should make it clear what points you didn't understand from your previous answers so that you don't get "repeat information" again and again.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima I liked your explanation, but I asked again because you didn't answer my questions that I stated, eg. "My main concern is where did we use 2/3K +1. What was the point of even figuring this out, wouldn't we have been fine with just ΔxΔx. I thought we would plug in 2/3K +1 where x is in each expansion like right/left sums."

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic @ Hamed, I have no idea where you got that from, there's no need to make elaborate tails. I get that I made mistakes in this question, i knew that when I posted it, because I was very frustrated no one could give me a clear simple explanation. That's no excuse on my part, but please don't make false accusations.

Comment: I would be fine if this question was closed, I understand it's a duplicate, but I really would appreciate if the answer below was somehow retained, it honestly a good answer.

Comment: Shanen, reasking a question is ALWAYS frowned upon. Why didn't you simply edit the first question, if you wanted to add clarifications to it?

Comment: That was my initial reaction @Jyrki Lahtonen, I made a minor change to see if the question would go to the top of the new questions section, but it didn't. So I assumed the question would be still 1 day old and no one would look at it. I thought if i made a new question it would go to the top again and someone would look at it. My apologies for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current state this question is almost unreadable, but I assume the question asks to find the lower sum of $f(x)=(x-2)^2+1$ on the interval $[1,3]$ when it is partitioned into $3$ parts.

First step would be to partition $[1,3]$ into $3$ parts of equal length: $\frac{3-1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$, so we can use the intervals: $[1,1+2/3],[1+2/3,1+4/3],[1+4/3,1+6/3]$, or equivalently, $[1,\frac53],[\frac53,\frac73],[\frac73,3]$. Call this partition $P$.

Apply the definition of the lower sum: $L(f,P)=\sum_{k=1}^3m_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$, where $m_k$ is the infimum of the function $f$ over the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. Here the $x_i$ represent the bounds of the intervals of the partition. Since we created partitions of equal length, we have that $(x_k-x_{k-1})=\frac{2}3$ for all partitions, so we reduce the problem to finding the value of $\frac23\sum_{k=1}^3m_k$.

To find the $m_k$, you would need to compute the infimums of the function in each interval. Luckily, the function is continuous and differentiable on a compact set, so by some theorems in analysis, the minimum is the infimum and it must be on the boundary of the set, or on a stationary point.

I will compute the first $m_k$ for reference, the rest you can do. So compute the minimum of $f$ on $[1,5/3]$ by finding the values at the boundaries: $f(1)=2, f(5/3)=10/9$. Finally look for stationary points in the interval: $f'(x)=2(x-2)=0\implies x=2$. $x=2$ is not in the interval $[1,5/3]$ so $m_1=10/9$.

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I wanted to know, I wanted it explained by definition and this is exactly it! I cannot stress how grateful I am.